# Well designed Registration form

Tags: jquery, forms, registration

I am developing .net application.I need some good looking registraion form using jquery.
please help me.

Comment: jquery is a javascript library. please use html and css to give good look to form.

Comment: If you are talking about website forms then for building form you do not jQuery its just plain html with some CSS for designing. jQuery is needed for validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build good looking form you need to know:
HTML, CSS, ASP.NET ( in your case ), Javascript (jQuery), Usability and Accessibility. You cannot learn all those in one question.

If you want jQuery Validation which will be hard to make work with ASP.NET so better use ASP.NER build-in validation which validate on client and server side per control